# How do I force iCal to sync?

Tags: macos, ical, google-calendar

I've recently set up my Google Calendars to hook into iCal on OS X Lion.  I've noticed though that when I make a change in iCal, it doesn't sync instantly to Google Calendar.

I'm sure that iCal will eventually sync when it gets a chance, but because I don't leave iCal open all day, I'd like the ability to force it to sync before I shut down.

Is this possible?

Comment: I use BusySync which allows you to manually sync with one click. Quite a good app.

Comment: Could you tell us how you have your calendar set up? Chiefly, information from iCal Preferences -> Accounts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I am aware, invoking iCal's "refresh" function, under the Calendar menu should do all server side communication and updates.

[image: iCal's Calendar Menu Options]

Refresh will only update the calendar that hosts the event you currently have (or last had) selected. Refresh All will of course update all of your calendars. This should be a two-way process, and not just pulling down new changes, it should also send local changes back assuming it's not being done automatically.

Comment: I've been using Command R for this for years with MobileMe and its still working fine with iCloud.

Comment: Ahhh of course, I could have sworn I went through all the menus but obviously not!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent in macOS Sierra's Calendar app is `View -> Refresh Calendars`.

Answer (score 0):

For Ventura, this did the trick for me:

```
killall calaccessd
```

You can verify it works by running this in a separate terminal before you execute that command:

```
log stream --predicate '(eventMessage CONTAINS "Calendar")' --debug --info
```

Comment: Refresh Calendars command still exists. Is there a reason you can't use that?

Comment: @Ezekiel I wanted the OS to sycn with the calendars in its Internet Accounts sources from the cmdline. I thought someone else might benefit from this.